# How to fix missing an Intermediate/chain certificate in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have installed nodejs and ssl on my sever

and my app.js code

```
var sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/cert.com.crt'),
  requestCert: true,
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt'),
  rejectUnauthorized: false 
};

var secureServer = https.createServer(sslOptions,app).listen(443, function(){
   console.log("Express server listening on port ");

});
```

Now when i check

**https://www.sslshopper.com/**

it is giving me error

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to
>   install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root
>   certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by
>   following Comodo's Certificate Installation Instructions for your
>   server platform (use these instructions for InstantSSL). Pay attention
>   to the parts about Intermediate certificates.

Any idea ?

How to fix this

Comment: I forgot to add ca: option and got "unable to verify the first certificate". added the bundle to complete the CA chain and it worked

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Comment out the line where you add the ca bundle. Copy all the text from ca.crt and paste them in cert.com.crt(don't replace the previous cert, just paste  under it). It should work fine now.

```
var sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/cert.com.crt'),
  requestCert: true,
  //ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt'),
  rejectUnauthorized: false 
};

var secureServer = https.createServer(sslOptions,app).listen(443, function(){
   console.log("Express server listening on port ");

});
```

Comment: Still having same problem

Comment: I found a very similar code [here](http://www.benjiegillam.com/2012/06/node-dot-js-ssl-certificate-chain/)

Comment: @HituBansal which is it?

Comment: Wow, this worked for me. I tested my nodeJS app with it's port on https://whatsmychaincert.com, it gave me a chain cert. and i added it as you suggested. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which file in Let'sEncrypt folder is analogous to `ca.crt`? We have: `cert.pem`  `chain.pem`  `fullchain.pem`  `privkey.pem`

Comment: @exebook See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59635929/543873).

Comment: How might one do this in redbirdjs?

Comment: I have been looking for this for the last 6 hrs, I didn't know it would be that simple.