# How to fix missing an Intermediate/chain certificate in nodejs with certificate of type .pfx

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have a certificate in .pfx format and when I use the below code and check the ssl using ssl checked i get intermediate certificate missing error.

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

        var credentials = {
            pfx: fs.readFileSync('C:/self/certificate/testname.com.pfx'),
            passphrase: "ffffff!"
        };

        this.app.server = https.createServer(credentials, this.app);
        this.app.server.timeout = 600000;
        this.init();

        const httpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
            res.writeHead(301, {Location: `https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`});
            res.end();
        });
        httpServer.listen(80);
    } else {
        this.app.server = http.createServer(this.app);
        this.init();
    }
```

Please let me know how to use it. I have already seen some posts like [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777760/how-to-fix-missing-an-intermediate-chain-certificate-in-nodejs/32778101)

But cannot find something that helps u to install a certificate of type .pfx. 
Help Appreciated.
-AJ

Answer (score 0):

After all the research and sample post [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777760/how-to-fix-missing-an-intermediate-chain-certificate-in-nodejs/32778101),

I generated the .crt, .ca-bundle and .pem file from the pfx file using openSSL and then appended all the lines from .ca-bundle to .crt file and then used below code.

```
var credentials = {

            key: fs.readFileSync('C:/testApp/certificate/private-key.pem'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('C:/testApp/certificate/certificate.crt'),

        };

        this.app.server = https.createServer(credentials, this.app);
```

and rerun the server. And all was good I was able to see the intermediate certificate chain successfully.
Thanks
-AJ