# Android WebView "Trust anchor for certification path not found" for LetsEncrypt cert

Tags: android, node.js, express, ssl

I have a web site being served over SSL from node.js.  When I visit the site with a web browser (both on the Desktop, *and* Android).  everything is fine - the lock appears indicating that the site is secure, when I inspect the certificates is valid and everything looks ok.  That should mean the server is set up correctly, right?

However, when I try to use an Android WebView for the exact same site, the page fails to load - I don't even see a request for the web page in my logs.  Andr, after relaxing the filter on logcat, I noticed this message:

```
I/X509Util: Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

In researching this a bit, one suggestion was that this is a configuration error on the server - that some part of the certificate isn't installed correctly.  I tested the site with an SSL analysis tool and discovered this:

> TLS Certificate is not trusted
>
> The certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (checking against Mozilla's root store). If you bought the certificate from a trusted authority, you probably just need to install one or more Intermediate certificates.

The certificate is from LetsEncrypt which by default puts four files in the directory for the site: privkey.pem, cert.pem, chain.pem, and fullchain.pem.  I am using the following code in node.js to load everything:

```
tls.createSecureContext({
        key: fs.readFileSync(dir+"/privkey.pem", "utf8"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(dir+"/cert.pem", "utf8")//,
        ca: fs.readFileSync(dir+"/chain.pem","utf8")
    })
```

From reading the [documentation on the createSecureContext](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options) function, I think the corresponding PEM files generated by LetsEncrypt are correct.  Specifically, it is my understanding that the `ca` parmameter pointing to the chain.pem file is what allows the intermediate CAs to be presented, which Android [requires](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#HttpsExample). However, just for good measure I also tried omitting the `ca` option (this should cause it to default the Mozilla's default chain), and changing `ca` to point to "fullchain.pem", neither of which made a difference.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

After experimenting with a few other things, I discovered that this works:

```
tls.createSecureContext({
    key: fs.readFileSync(dir+"/privkey.pem", "utf8"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(dir+"/fullchain.pem", "utf8")
})
```

I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778101/543873) although it is not referring to the naming convention used by LetsEncrypt so I had to adapt it a bit.

Comment: You are a savior.